# How to print matching json element value from nested json string

Tags: python, python-3.6

my_json file has list of nested dicts, I need to print only the username if `type==Developer-Verified and it's value==1`, I managed to print just the approvals list, unable to to go further.

```
$ cat myjson_file | python3.6 -c "import sys, json; approvals=json.load(sys.stdin)['currentPatchSet']['approvals']; print(json.dumps(approvals, indent=4))"

[
    {
        "type": "Developer-Verified",
        "description": "Developer-Verified",
        "value": "1",
        "grantedOn": 1581451370,
        "by": {
            "name": "Donald Snifer",
            "email": "dsnifer@gmail.com",
            "username": "dsnifer"
        }
    },
    {
        "type": "Code-Review",
        "description": "Code-Review",
        "value": "2",
        "grantedOn": 1581623684,
        "by": {
            "name": "Brandon Welch",
            "email": "bwelch@gmail.com",
            "username": "bwelch"
        }
    },
    {
        "type": "Developer-Verified",
        "description": "Developer-Verified",
        "value": "1",
        "grantedOn": 1581451370,
        "by": {
            "name": "Hamlin Damer",
            "email": "hdamer@gmail.com",
            "username": "hdamer"
        }
    }
]
$
```

I need to print just `dsnifer hdamer`

I tried to move further with below and other logics, and I keep failing
`python3.6 -c "import sys, json; approvals=json.load(sys.stdin)['currentPatchSet']['approvals']; print( k for k,v in approvals[0].items())"`

Comment: How would you solve the problem if you simply had a list of dicts? **Because you do**. For that matter: if you had **one of** those dicts, would you be able to write the code that checks whether it meets the criteria? If you have a list, can you write code that checks each element of the list to see if they meet a condition? If you put those things together, does that somehow not solve the problem? Where exactly are you stuck?

Answer (score 0):

Loop inside json and check if type and value meet's the condition if so just print the username.

```
for ele in jsonData :
    if ele['type'] == 'Developer-Verified' and ele['value'] == '1' :
        print(ele["by"]["username"], end=" ")
```